# Please replace pages that have responsive design with those versions on mobile

Tags: feature-request, design, mobile-web

The responsive design is very nice on pages like [the homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ac6pZ.png) (has a theme, more buttons on the top than [mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znRER.png)) and has extra functionality on [questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3roB.png) (view votes) and the [asking UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHjrQ.png) (all the formatting buttons unlike [mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2DX1.png)).

I really like this version of the site. However, on things like [Chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTEsX.jpg), it is non-existent and having it in desktop mode makes the text quite hard to read and I have to zoom in and scroll.

**Please set the responsive design to be the default style rather than the mobile on all pages that have it in a form that works**, i.e. questions, the homepage, asking questions, [tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MshQP.png), *maybe* the editing UI, and more that I don't think of.

<sub>It's pretty effective on [the flags page, too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GF0fb.png), which would be nice if it were linked on the profile on mobile, too (not super relevant...</sub>

Comment: What’s wrong with this proposal? The responsive design is much more functional on pages where it works but annoying to have to manually switch to to get to review queues and stuff

Comment: The title could use some rewording.  The first few times I read it, I thought it was asking for exactly the opposite of what the longer question actually asks.  (And no, _I_ didn't downvote it, so this isn't an answer to your "What's wrong" comment.)

Comment: Despite the responsive design, the site is still "heavy" when loading the full site; lots of mobile users are from places with slow network connections or bandwidth caps, and they benefit from having the mobile site.

Comment: @sonic oh that makes sense. I would like the top buttons to be on the mobile site, if not have the full site load by default.

Comment: Even a single load of the full site can have onerous bandwidth constraints, as it also loads more functionality; I'd prefer that the low-bandwidth version be the default while users have the option of using the full-bandwidth one. Also, responsive design is still officially considered "beta".

Answer (score 5):

Chat doesn't have a responsive design yet. I'm pretty sure it doesn't run on the Stacks front end framework, though I suppose that might end up being an eventual goal.

If you switch to "desktop" mode once, that's remembered; I use *some* main sites on desktop mode on a phone, even before responsive design, and in some respects the "simplified" mobile view still has a few advantages.

*Eventually*, the goal is to move everything over to responsive design and Stacks, if I understand correctly. It's not "eventually" yet.

So, on the short term, if you *really* want responsive design, use it. That said, its going to be a (long?) while before responsive design comes to chat. It's not exactly a high priority at the moment, and is unlikely to be until a pile of other projects gets done.

Comment: I said that Chat doesn’t have a responsive design. If I switch to desktop on Safari, it messes up Chat and is annoying (have to restart app). I’d like to have all the other pages’ functionality on the mobile site without having to switch back and forth. What is the point or having mobile be different from responsive for all those pages?

Comment: @Stormblessed in Safari, is "use desktop site" (or similar wording) not a per-site configuration?  It is in some other browsers, which would let you set it differently for chat.se.com and otherstuff.se.com -- though you might have to set it for each individual site, once.

Comment: Its literally something that *just* started rolling out, even on regular sites, and is distinct from the classic pre-stacks design. There's no equivalent for chat (yet?) so without moving chat to 'stacks' - and a partial move would be messy, what you ask for would be unlikely, and it would be a *major* enterprise.

Comment: @MonicaCellio it's not; Chat becomes desktop if I load it after going into desktop on any other Stack Exchange webpage

Comment: That's odd. I run SU and MSE in desktop/responsive mode, and MSE and SE chat in mobile mode, switching chat to desktop mode *only* for emergency moderation and image uploads

Comment: @Stormblessed did you click the 'mobile' link on the bottom of the Chat page to force the 'mobile' view?

Comment: @NoDistractionWizard Oh, I never noticed that button!! Thanks!